# emacs-nox framebuffer access

Tags: terminal-emacs, emacs-nox

First of all, I am not familiar with how `emacs-nox` is implemented internally.
Suppose we can access framebuffer directly (`/dev/fb...`)
Is it possible to access the framebuffer directly using emacs?
For example, I want to view pictures or pdfs using `emacs-nox`.
I believe this is totally feasible since I can see pictures and videos on tty using `fbi` or `mplayer`.

Answer (score 0):

No, emacs has no capability for using the framebuffer. You're right that it wouldn't be impossible to add it, but apparently it's never been done.